# Traversing Neo4j database using Python

Tags: python, neo4j, nodes, graph-databases, nosql

I have a Neo4j graph database with more than 100,000 nodes and almost double the relationships. What is the best approach to traverse the entire db using Python?

Answer (score 3):

Use the py2neo module, connect to a REST endpoint for a neo4j server, issue whatever traversal you want in cypher, and process the results.

[Here are some documentation pointers on how to do that](https://py2neo.org/v4/data.html).

You need to write a cypher query which does the traversal you want, and feeds you the results in the right order though.   A trivial query `MATCH n RETURN n` will return all nodes in the database.   A trivial query `MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN r` will return all relationships in the database.

Depending on what order you want your traversal in and what kind of data you have, go from there.  Make sure to process each result one at a time, and do not materialize all of your results in memory.